# Как правильно употреблять слова

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов

Здравствуйте. 
Подскажите пожалуйста какое слово "экземпляр" или "штука" правильней употреблять применительно к вещам или изделиям? Например окна, двери, столы, стулья.
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Проще обходиться в речи без этих слов: пять окон, двое дверей, десять столов, двенадцать стульев. Но, скорей всего, вас интересуют какие-то документы.  Тогда уж считайте **в штуках** или **предметах**.
Слово ЭКЗЕМПЛЯР для обозначения предметов мебели как-то не очень подходит.
**ЭКЗЕМПЛЯ́Р**, а, м. [нем. Exemplar < лат. exemplar образец].1.Отдельный предмет из ряда подобных ***(обычно о печатном или рукописном тексте)***.Тираж в тысячу экземпляров.||Ср. штука (в 1-м знач.).2.Отдельный представитель какого-н. разряда животных, растений.Редкий э. орхидеи.3. разг. шутл.То же, что тип (в 5-м знач.).Ну и э. этот ваш знакомый!
*Яндекс.Словари › Толковый словарь иноязычных слов. — 2004*
**ШТУ́КА**, и, ж. [польск. sztuka < ср.-в.-нем. stücke кусок].1.Отдельный предмет из числа однородных, считаемых.Пять штук яиц.||Ср. экземпляр (в 1-м знач.).2. устар.В нек-рых сочетаниях: предмет как целое.Ш. полотна.
*Яндекс.Словари › Толковый словарь иноязычных слов. — 2004*

Answer (score 0):

Экземпляр - это образец, отдельный предмет из ряда ему подобных.
Штука - счётная единица.

Поэтому при счёте уместнее называть "штуками", а отдельные уникальные изделия "экземплярами".

*К нам поступило пять штук столов. Два экземпляра изделия оказались с незначительными дефектами.*

Вообще, слово "экземпляр" как правило используют для печатной продукции. *Книга издана тиражём 100000 экземпляров*.

Answer (score 0):

> Вообще, слово "экземпляр" ,как правило, используют для печатной продукции. Книга издана тиражОм 100000 экземпляров.